# WPF frame source questions

Tags: wpf, frame

I've created a WPF application with a frame inside. I can attach some other pages to this frame like

frame1.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

The question is after loading this page (Page1.xaml) an Load another page in the same frame (Page2.xaml)
is the Page1.xaml disposed automaticly or is it still running in background? I could not find a dispose method for a frame source page. Can anyone explain this please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Frame` is designed to provide the ability for navigating content; the preferred way to package content for navigation is a `Page` as you are doing. Specifically, the Frame can be navigated with the Navigate methods and **will maintain the lifetime of navigation history**, where "history" is the keyword here.

Within the history of the navigation, the Frame **will not maintain an instance of each Page** navigated to avoid excessive memory consumption. Consequently, the state is not remembered when using the Navigation controls and a new instance is created each time the page is navigated to.

In other words, when you navigate away from a page in a frame, the object is disposed.

[MSDN has a good read on using Frames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx).